# nil pointer embedded error

Tags: go, null

Why do I get a nil pointer error when I try to print a pointer with an uninitialized embedded error:

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "errors"
)

type Danger struct {
  error
}

func main() {
  // the nil pointer issue has to do with struct embedding an error value that is nil
  d := &Danger{}
  log.Println(d)

  d = &Danger{errors.New("foobar")}
  log.Println(d)
}
```

results in

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 %!v(PANIC=runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference)
2009/11/10 23:00:00 foobar
```

https://play.golang.org/p/fBuN0XonX9v

This came up in an interview today and neither interviewer nor interviewee could figure it out.

Comment: Are you asking why calling `Error()` on a nil `error` panics, or why the panic output is formatted in the log?

Comment: I guess I'm wondering why a nil pointer exception is occurring in the first place.

Comment: It may be easier to understand if you [build the "base" type yourself instead of using `error`](https://play.golang.org/p/W7jHpWGweMs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) says:

> Given a struct type S and a defined type T, promoted methods are included in the method set of the struct as follows:
>
> - If S contains an embedded field T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S also includes promoted methods with receiver *T.

The [fmt](http://godoc.org/fmt) documentation says:

> If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

From this, we can conclude that `log.Println(d)` will invoke the promoted Error method from the `error` field.

If the `error` field is `nil`, then the call panics.

The fmt documentation also says:

> If an Error or String method triggers a panic when called by a print routine, the fmt package reformats the error message from the panic, decorating it with an indication that it came through the fmt package.

The text `%!v(PANIC=runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference)` is the decorated panic value.